# Alternate to quoteInto Method for Pdo queries

Tags: mysql, magento, zend-framework, pdo

```
        $conditions[] = $this->getConnection()
            ->quoteInto('cat_index.category_id IN (?)', "{$filters[category_id]},{$Catids}");
```

quote into encaps my values in quotes. I want to use this same method without the quoteInto method. So basically, I would like to know what method does the samething without adding quotes

Comment: I dunno Zend but [with raw PDO you will need some hand work](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15991146/285587)

Answer (score 1):

In order to use a parameterized query with `in`, you must specify the number of parameters with `?` (or some value) even with `in`.

```
cat_index.category_id IN (?,?)
```

You can do this with an array of the arguments.

```
// array_merge Catids instead? is it an array?
$args = array($filters["category_id"], $Catids);
$query = "cat_index.category_id IN (" .
    implode(',', array_fill(0, count($args), '?'))
    . ")";
foreach ($args as $arg) {
    $connection->quoteInto($query, $arg);
}
```

Comment: your solution did not work. quoteInto wraps quotations around my values still, I am passing integers

Comment: @numerical25 that doens't matter; MySQL will treat them the same in the query whether they have quotes around them or not if they are integers.

Comment: Yea, I figured out my issue. I was parsing the values from a string and PDO was therefore treating the values as a string instead of a integer. I had to convert each value to a integer using the intval() method before passing it into the quoteInto method

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I was parsing the values from a string and therefore the $Cateids were treated as if they were a string and not a integer. I did the following

```
    $values = $values ? array_filter(explode('_', $values)) : array();
    $i = 0;
    foreach($values as $v) {
        $values[$i] = intval($v);
    }
```

followed by

```
        $query = "cat_index.category_id IN (" .
            implode(',', array_fill(0, count($values), "?")). ")";
        foreach($values as $v) {
            $conditions[] = $this->getConnection()->quoteInto($query,$v);
        }
```

now the values being passed are treated like integers instead of being wrapped in quotations

Answer (score -1):

Assuming `$filters['category_id']` is not an array, but `$Catids` is, you probably want:

```
->quoteInto('cat_index.category_id IN (?)', array_merge(array($filters['category_id']), $Catids));
```

**Edit**: you can also do:

```
->quoteInto('cat_index.category_id IN (?)', array_merge(array($filters['category_id']), $Catids), 'INTEGER');
```

if you're sure the values are numeric - this will ensure you don't get quotes around the individual values. MySQL works perfectly well with quoted integers though.

Comment: quoteInto does exactly what I dont want it to do. it wraps the values in quotation. I am passing integers so therefore they do not need to be wrapped in quotes

Comment: Are you saying it wraps each value in a quote, like `'1','2','3'`, or the comma separated value: `'1,2,3'`?